# return value in compare() function of SplHeap class

Tags: php

"Hello Everybody"
in the first note of php manual : splheap class there is example I can't understand the line of return in compare() function of splheap subclass

the line I can't understand

```
return $values1[0] < $values2[0] ? -1 : 1;
```

The example :

> ```
> To have a good idea what you can do with SplHeap, I created a little example script that will show the rankings of Belgian soccer
> ```

```
<?php
/**
* A class that extends SplHeap for showing rankings in the Belgian
* soccer tournament JupilerLeague
*/
class JupilerLeague extends SplHeap 
{
    /**
     * We modify the abstract method compare so we can sort our
     * rankings using the values of a given array
     */
    public function compare($array1, $array2)
    {
        $values1 = array_values($array1);
        $values2 = array_values($array2);
        if ($values1[0] === $values2[0]) return 0;
        return $values1[0] < $values2[0] ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

// Let's populate our heap here (data of 2009)
$heap = new JupilerLeague();
$heap->insert(array ('AA Gent' => 15));
$heap->insert(array ('Anderlecht' => 20));
$heap->insert(array ('Cercle Brugge' => 11));
$heap->insert(array ('Charleroi' => 12));
$heap->insert(array ('Club Brugge' => 21));
$heap->insert(array ('G. Beerschot' => 15));
$heap->insert(array ('Kortrijk' => 10));
$heap->insert(array ('KV Mechelen' => 18));
$heap->insert(array ('Lokeren' => 10));
$heap->insert(array ('Moeskroen' => 7));
$heap->insert(array ('Racing Genk' => 11));
$heap->insert(array ('Roeselare' => 6));
$heap->insert(array ('Standard' => 20));
$heap->insert(array ('STVV' => 17));
$heap->insert(array ('Westerlo' => 10));
$heap->insert(array ('Zulte Waregem' => 15));
```

Can you help me please to understand this line ??

Answer (score 0):

It's a [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) statement. It means:

```
if ($values1[0] < $values2[0]) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

The ternary operator is not specific to `SplHeap`. It's just a general use PHP operator.

Answer (score 0):

It's a conditional ternay operator `?`(a ternary `if`).

How does it works?:

> In computer programming, `?:` is a ternary operator that is part of the
>   syntax for a basic conditional expression in several programming
>   languages. It is commonly referred to as the conditional operator,
>   inline if (iif), or ternary if.
>
> It originally comes from CPL, in which equivalent syntax for `e1 ? e2 : e3`
>   was `e1 → e2, e3`.
>
> Although many ternary operators are possible, the conditional operator
>   is so common, and other ternary operators so rare, that the
>   conditional operator is commonly referred to as the ternary operator.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

For example, using your code:

```
return $values1[0] < $values2[0] ? -1 : 1;
```

It's similar to say:

```
if($values1[0] < $values2[0]){
     return -1;
}
else{
     return 1;
}
```

The `?` works as a `then`, and the `:` works as a `else`